# HtmlAgilityPack - Selecting Multiple Nodes

Tags: linq, html-agility-pack, windows-phone-8.1

As there's no official release of `HtmlAgilityPack` for `windows phone 8.1 or WinRT`, Referencing manually the dll doesn't allow to call the `SelectNodes()` function where I can pass a `XPATH` as parameter.

I'm looking for an similar Linq query by which I can select multiple nodes depending of the node's class name. In Plain English I want store the all the nodes in a `HtmlNodeCollection` where the node starts with `div` and the `class` of that `div` is XXX.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's significantly more efficient for us to help fix existing code than try and write it fresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translated from your sentence into HtmlAgilityPack's LINQ expression :

```
var result = doc.DocumentNode
                .Descendants()
                .Where(o => o.Name.StartsWith("div") 
                                && 
                            o.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "XXX");
```

or simply mention that you are interested only in `<div>` nodes :

```
var result = doc.DocumentNode
                .Descendants("div")
                .Where(o => o.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "XXX");
```

Above returns `IEnumerable<HtmlNode>` instead of `HtmlNodeCollection`, but that isn't significant IMHO.